# How to access data of [object object] AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to AngularJS.
I am sending a JsonObject to another state.

Ex:

```
viewScope.edit=function(d) {

   var viewData = {
      'name' : d.name,
   };

   $state.go('edit', {'viewD': viewData}, {reload: true});
};
```

My State is-

```
viewApp.config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('edit', {
            name: '#/edit',
            url: '/register/{viewD}',
            templateUrl: function(){    
                 return path+'/register.jsp';
             },
             controller:'registerCtrl',
             resolve : {
                 loadPlugin: function($ocLazyLoad) {
                     return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                         name : 'registerApp',
                         files: [path+'/resources/js/register.js'],
                     }])
                }
            }
        })
});
```

In register Controller getting data-

```
regApp.controller('registerCtrl',function($stateParams){                 
        if($stateParams != undefined){
            console.log($stateParams.viewD);
        }
});
```

**On console output is- [object object]**

How can i access the **name** key from this [object object].

**console.log($StateParams.viewD.name); // Not Working**

**JSON.parse, JSON.stringify not working.**

Comment: What is the content of `$stateParams` ? What is the type of `$stateParams.viewD` ?

Comment: @Weedoze The content of $stateParams is viewD : "[object Object]"

Comment: Where do you see this `[object Object]` ? In the console ? Can you expand it ? What is the result of `console.log(typeof $stateParamas.viewD)`

Comment: @Weedoze  yes in the console. No i can not expand it. Its type is String

Comment: Try to replace your url in the state config by `url: '/register/{viewD:json}',`

Comment: @Weedoze now it can be navigate but when i  do this console.log($stateParams.viewD.name);  then error come during app load time. Undefined name

Comment: @Weedoze Thanks man it worked. Add answer in the post so that i can accept your answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've added my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your state config URL from

```
url: '/register/{viewD}',
```

to

```
url: '/register/{viewD:json}',
```

The JSON parameter type has been added in version [0.2.13](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/027f1fcf9c0916cea651e88981345da6f9ff214a)

Answer (score 1):

Change your config method as following,

```
viewApp.config(function($stateProvider){
$stateProvider
    .state('edit', {
        name: '#/edit',
        url: '/register',
        params: {
           viewD: null
        }
        templateUrl: function(){    
             return path+'/register.jsp';
         },
         controller:'registerCtrl',
         resolve : {
             loadPlugin: function($ocLazyLoad) {
                 return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                     name : 'registerApp',
                     files: [path+'/resources/js/register.js'],
                 }])
            }
        }
    })
});
```

And then you can access your object from `$state` like this in the controller,
`$state.params.viewD` or from `$stateParams` like this `$stateParams.viewD`

Now try `console.log($state.params.viewD.name)`

Comment: console.log($stateParams.viewD); output= {name : "abc"} but console.log($stateParams.viewD.name); gives error during app load undefined name.

Comment: Try this and see the type of your viewD `console.log(typeof $stateParams.viewD)`, if it's a `string` `JSON.parse($stateParams.viewD).name` would return the name

Comment: Give error --- SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 on JSON.parse($stateParams.viewD).name

Comment: Seems like your `$stateParams.viewD` object is undefined. `if($stateParams.viewD) JSON.parse($stateParams.viewD).name` try this. If it doesn't go inside the if check your source of the viewD

Comment: Its not undefined it came under if($StateParams.viewD){ and still error. What i do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169414/discussion-between-senal-and-deepak-verma).